# Seemingly simple UL list adding extra padding, can't figure out

Tags: css

Here's my code and everything looks okay to me, but for whatever reason the LIs are creating extra padding at the bottom.

What am I missing? Here's the Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/M8eRG/

```
<ul class="project-thumbs">
                <li><img src="http://wiki.urbandead.com/images/1/1c/Square.gif"></li>
                <li><img src="http://wiki.urbandead.com/images/1/1c/Square.gif"></li>

            </ul>


.project-thumbs {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
.project-thumbs li{
    background:#cc3300;
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you looking at the code with? Have you checked to see how it looks in others?

Comment: It's doing this in Chrome and Firefox on my Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are not displayed as block elements by default, hence they "create a line". You can alter that behavior by specifying this:

```
.project-thumbs li img
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this in the li itself

```
.project-thumbs li{
    background:#cc3300;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```